# How do you tell C++ to use a specific file from a folder when you don't always know the exact path?

Tags: c++

Note: I only know C in depth at the moment, but I am enrolled in a summer course starting soon on modern C++, so methods for C++20 would be extremely helpful as well. If this is a dumb question or was already asked (I didn't find anything from googling), then links would be helpful as well.

**Question:**

Okay, so say I am designing a program. I want the program to fopen a file, and I can either tell it the exact path, or have it in my working directory. Let's make up two paths below for the sake of example:

- (my computer path)/project/partone/mainfiles/main.c
- (my computer path)/project/parttwo/mainfiles/data.csv

Now this isn't normally a problem, because I can just give main.c the full path to data.csv. But what if I want to publish the program? Then whoever downloads it will have a different path on their computer, automatically making the code fail.

Is there any way to do this in C++20 (preferred answer) and/or C99 (if you know it for C99, that at least gives me some keywords to google for C++20, and I heard C code for the most part is usable in C++).

I was thinking maybe there is like some package in C++20 that could act sort of like the "cd" command in the Linux Terminal where it can change directories starting at the one I am in? Like tell C++ to (from project/partone/mainfiles):

```
//pseudocode
cd ..
cd ..
cd parttwo
cd mainfiles
fopen data.csv
```

Comment: Do it like any other program does, ask the user to tell it where the file is

Comment: Or toss the starting location in the registry or some other fixed-location source of information. Program goes to one place to get the information that can vary.

Comment: ... or provide appropriate configuration files for your program,  to avoid user interaction.

Comment: On *nixen, store it in a hidden folder under your user’s `$HOME` directory. Opening such a file in C++ using the `<filesystem>` library is trivial.

Comment: On Windows, you can do the same as on Linux. That said, you _should_ have the OS tell you where the user’s data directory is (usually in ~/AppData/Roaming, but get it from the OS anyway).

Comment: _@PlutoniumSlime_ stop referring to C/C++, these are different programming languages!

Comment: @NathanOliver That's a really good idea that I feel stupid for not thinking about. I'll have to google how to do that, thank you! I'm going to leave the question up for now since maybe someone else has a way to do it relative to the main.c file (not because I don't accept your method, but rather cause I am genuinely curious and want to learn more). I'll probably end up doing that though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry! I am still new, my professor said that C++ was just an extension of C (granted, he only knows C).

Comment: @Dúthomhas I have no clue how that all works, what would be some good keywords or phrases I could look up to learn more about these sort of processes?

Comment: @user4581301: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering (but I'm not sure I've ever totally believed it).

Comment: @PaulSanders works often enough that even if it lacks a few edge cases, it's a great starting point.

Comment: You might want to review [ask]. An opening paragraph full of excuses and personal background is a big turn-off for people who are scanning for questions they feel confident answering. Ideally, by the end of the opening paragraph, a reader should know that your program has to access two files, and you don't know where either is (or is it just the second one that's a problem -- this is not clear in your question). More details can follow that. If you feel you must post excuses, they can go at the end, the place of least prominence.

Comment: *"maybe there is like some [...] 'cd' command in the Linux Terminal where it can change directories"* -- how would this help? You earlier stated that the path will be different for each person that downloads the program. This implies that there is no way to guess the files' locations. Yet somehow you know where the first is going to be? And somehow from the first location, you can find the second? Such details, if true, should be part of your question. The more precisely you can define your requirements, the better.

Comment: Question: _I'm going to open **a** file_ What file?  What is its purpose?

Comment: @PaulSanders There are a lot of files, so I just used a made up example so I didn't have to explain the entire purpose of what the program is doing. Opening a .csv file doesn't change depending on the data inside, only the process of parsing it does.

Comment: @JaMiT Good point.... I never thought of that...

Comment: @PlutoniumSlime Have a look at the [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem) library in C++11 and later. The [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) class makes working with paths much easier.

Comment: You should try.  As currently written, the question is meaningless.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! It really helps a lot and I sincerely appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a little helper module to get a path to a creatable/writable directory for saving your program data.

**appdata_path.hpp**

```
#ifndef APPDATA_PATH_HPP
#define APPDATA_PATH_HPP

#include <filesystem>
#include <string>

std::filesystem::path
get_appdata_path( const std::string & application_name );

#endif
```

**appdata_path.cpp**

```
#include "appdata_path.hpp"

#ifdef _WIN32

  #include <windows.h>
  #include <shlobj.h>
  #include <objbase.h>

  #pragma comment(lib,"Shell32")
  #pragma comment(lib,"Ole32")

  std::filesystem::path
  get_known_folder_path( REFKNOWNFOLDERID rfid )
  {
    wchar_t * p;
    if (S_OK != SHGetKnownFolderPath( rfid, 0, NULL, &p )) return "";
    std::filesystem::path result = p;
    CoTaskMemFree( p );
    return result;
  }

  std::filesystem::path
  get_appdata_path( const std::string & application_name )
  {
    auto path = get_known_folder_path( FOLDERID_LocalAppData );  // or FOLDERID_RoamingAppData
    if (!path.empty()) path /= application_name;
    return path;
  }

#else

  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <pwd.h>
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <unistd.h>

  std::filesystem::path
  get_appdata_path( const std::string & application_name )
  {
    const char * p = getenv( "HOME" );
    if (p) return p + ("/" + application_name);

    struct passwd * pw = getpwuid( getuid() );
    if (pw) return pw->pw_dir + ("/" + application_name);

    return "";
  }

#endif
```

**example.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "appdata_path.hpp"

int main()
{
  auto path = get_appdata_path( "Example Application" );
  if (path.empty()) std::cout << "Wut?\n";
  else              std::cout << path << "\n";
}
```

Notes:

- Notice that the Windows code has a choice between Local and Roaming. Unless you plan for your app to work across multiple computers, use Local.
- Certain characters are not valid in filenames (on Windows). In general you should avoid weird characters when naming files anyway, so use a simplified, filesystem-friendly name for your application. As you see in the example, spaces are OK, but whether you use them or not is up to you.
- Notice that the code does nothing but return a valid path. It does *not* create or verify the existence of the path. You must do that yourself.

For example, to save data you might use something like:

```
void save_data()
{
  auto save_directory = get_appdata_path( "Quuxer" );
  auto save_filename = save_directory / "data.csv";
  if (save_directory.empty())
    std::filesystem::create_directory( save_directory );
  std::ofstream f( save_filename );
  f << my_data;
}
```

This module compiles on Windows with MSVC as-is. If you use a different compiler (GCC or LLVM/Clang) you will need to explicitly link with `Shell32.lib` and `Ole32.lib`.

It compiles on Linux (and Mac too!) as-is.

Requires C++17, I think.